# Show items of specific type from ObservableCollection in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Im designing a programm where you can buy and sell computerparts, just to get used to MVVM.
My Model contains the class Gpu and Cpu, both inhert from Product which is abstract.
In my ViewModel I have a ObservableCollection of Product:

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList { get; set; }

ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product(core.Repository.GetAll<Product>());
```

In my View I have 2 DataGrids, one for Gpus and one for Cpus.
I want to show only the name of all Gpus from my ProductList on the Gpu DataGrid without creating an additional List.

My XAML Code:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <vm:ProductViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

With this code the DataGrid shows me the name of both Products, Gpus and Cpus,
is there a easy way to only show items of type Gpu?

Comment: How are you distinguishing CPUs and GPUs in the Products. Is there any bool field for the same?

Comment: I dont distinguish them in Products, they just have different propertys like the Cpu class have CoreCount and the Gpu class have ShaderCount.
I want to distinguish them just by the type, I can do this in C# with:
IEnumerable<Gpu> GpuList = ProductList.OfType<Gpu>();

Comment: Can you show how are you populating `core.Repository.GetAll<Product>()`?

Comment: This is the function in my Repository: 
`public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : Entity
 {
      return context.Set<T>().ToList();
 }`
And my context class includes Entity Framework and inherts from DbContext

Comment: Why dont you do it from the code behind?

Comment: because I dont want to make so many lists, when I want to add more items like RAM or Motherboard I will have many lists. But only having one list which contains all Products would be clearer I guess, its also will be more confortable to Bind the selected item.
That's what you mean by doing it from the code behind right @RichaGarg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to filter out different product types to show in `DataGrid` . Like maybe you will have a `ComboBox` that will contain a list of your product types and on selecting a product type, your `DataGrid` shows only products of those types.

Your best solution is to use a `CollectionViewSource` to bind to `DataGrid` instead of simple `ObservableCollection`.

`CollectionViewSource` offers a `Filter` Method that lets you show only selected items in the `DataGrid` even if the `ObservableCollection` has all items.

You can do Something like this.

Define a reference of type `ICollectionView` which will contain `CollectionView` of your `ObservableCollection<Product>`

```
private ICollectionView productListView = null;

public ICollectionView ProductListView
{
   get { return productListView; }
   set { productListView = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductListView"); }
}

private ObservableCollection<Product> productList;
```

Make expicit `getter` and `setter` so that you are allowed to fill the `CollectionView` whenever `ProductList` Collection is set.

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList
{
    get { return productList; }
    set
    {
        productList = value;
        ProductListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(value);
        ProductListView.Filter = FilterMethod;
    }
}
```

If you see above `ProductListView` is filled with `DefaultView` of the `ObservableCollection<Product>`

Then fill the `ProductList` like you were doing already.

```
ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>(core.Repository.GetAll<Product>());
```

Now here comes the `Filter` Method that does the job you want. It will filter out only the `Objects` of type `Gpu`. And only those objects will be shown in the `DataGrid`

```
private bool FilterMethod(object item)
{
    return item is Gpu ? true : false;
}
```

[CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now the final part will be to bind the `CollectionView` to `DataGrid` instead of `ObservableCollection`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductListView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you have used `ViewModel` instead of Code Behind to bind data to `XAML`. So the above code can be inserted into `ViewModel` as well. Hope that solves the issue you are facing.

Comment: Its not working.
The ProductListView contains one Gpu but it doesnt show it on the DataGrid.
Do the ICollectionView have the features from the ObservableCollection to update the UI when it changes, or do I have make something in the constructor of the ViewModel?

Comment: I think you have to notify property changed in ProductListView setter. Also add UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" in DataGrid Binding. I have edited my answer